# cpufreq_get returns 0 in linux kernel module

Tags: c, linux, cpu, kernel-module, sysfs

I have written the following code to get current CPU frequency in my kernel module C file:

```
#include <linux/cpufreq.h>

void func() {
  printk(KERN_ALERT "CPU Freq in KHz: %d\n", cpufreq_get(3));
}
```

I am getting `CPU Freq in KHz: 0`
I have checked that my kernel is built with `CONFIG_CPU_FREQ=y`, `CONFIG_X86_INTEL_PSTATE=y` with the following code `grep -i cpu_freq /boot/config-$(uname -r)` and `grep -i pstate /boot/config-$(uname -r)`.

I can check frequency easily in the sysfs file system:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
```

Why is it not accessible in Linux Kernel module?

The user-space utility `cpufreq-info` is also giving output about current CPU frequency.
I am running on Ubuntu 16.04 X86_64.

**EDIT:**
The following code also outputs `CPU Freq in KHz: 0`:

```
void func() {
#ifdef CONFIG_CPU_FREQ
    printk(KERN_ALERT "CPU Freq in KHz: %d\n", cpufreq_get(3));
#endif
}
```

Therefore, `CONFIG_CPU_FREQ` is surely defined. I have checked with #pragma and it has `1` value.

Comment: You probably need to include the kernel header with the current configurations (kconfig.h) so that you get CONFIG_CPU_FREQ defined before cpufreq.h is included. In kernel space, if that isn't defined, cpufreq.h replaces the cpufreq_get() call with an inline static definition that always returns 0.

Comment: Please see my edit. I have checked and `CONFIG_CPU_FREQ` is defined.

Comment: cpufreq_get() works on a test module I wrote (Fedora 23, kernel 4.8.13). The scaling_cur_freq code in the kernel uses arch_freq_get_on_cpu() when the cpufreq driver is not active. See this test module: https://github.com/fbergo/freqmod , one of the two printed values should be the current frequency (I get 0 on f[0], 1400000 on f[1] on my machine).

Comment: I think Fedora might have a different cpufreq driver. My driver is `intel_pstate`. I checked. `arch_freq_get_on_cpu` is not even defined in my case. `cpufreq_get` and `cpufreq_generic_get` both are not working.